# Ticked at me" what does it mean?

Tags: verbs, nouns

What does this sentence mean:

> My girlfriend *ticked at me*.

I did not find any meaning for that .

Comment: Do you have a longer quote, or a source? Without some kind of context it's really hard to say (and I'm almost tempted to say that it doesn't make sense - I only know of "to tick" meaning "a clock making a sound" or "to write a checkmark on a piece of paper", so "ticking at someone" seems weird to me)

Comment: Yes, "was ticked off" is the expected grammar. But she could have been pretending to be a clock, standing above you, saying "tick-tock" and counting time. – SF. 37 mins ago

Answer (score 3):

I believe you mean:

> My girlfriend was ticked off at me.

The expression *ticked off* means annoyed.
It is just another expression of annoyance similar to *cheesed off*, *hacked off* and several others similar.